# getting gmail message read information

Tags: gmail-api

I started looking at the gmail API for an application I am working on. I tried looking for an API I can use to determine if the recipient opened or read the message, but it doesn't look like there is one. Is this correct?

The assumptions are:

- Both sender and recipient are gmail accounts
- Sender does not have access to recipient gmail account
- Access through the API is limited to the Sender (can authenticate Sender)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmail or Gmail-Api don't have this feature. There is in general no reliable way of detecting whether the email is opened or not.

There are a lot of resources on the web such as this [one](http://easykey.uk/email-tips/how-can-i-know-has-my-email-been-read).

In general you should try to embed a picture or some script whether the email is opened or not and track the openings in a server.